# Intent to Battery Launch section in Huawei with Oreo

Tags: android-intent, launch, battery, android-8.0-oreo, huawei-mobile-services

I need to redirect the Huawei users with Android 8 "Oreo" to the new section Settings -> Battery -> Launch

Anyone knows how to build the intent or where I could find the information (package and class) to create it?

Comment: Apparently Google Play policy prohibits requesting users to white-list apps to sidestep battery optimizations, unless your app absolutely needs it to function (i.e. medical alert, etc). You might want to google it further.

Comment: Hi @Le-royStaines thanks for your replay, actually I need it because it is an emergency app. In previous versión I found the way to send the user to the screen and they were who enable-disable battery optimizations, but in android 8 I have no idea of how to do it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was facing the same problem and using accessibility I have try to get the class name or activity name to pass in intent and open the Settings -> Battery -> Launch

tested on Oreo Huawei Honor 9 Lite:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.appcontrol.activity.StartupAppControlActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Its a little late but maybe can help someone and save time.

Comment: No so late... it works on Huawei P with Android 8.0, thank you so much!

Comment: Can I specify a package name so it display an app launch settings directly?

Comment: @Ton yes you can use package name  but package name is used to open the application with default screen and if you want to open some specific screen then you have to mentioned the activity also i think